# Error with Scanner.close() on using my methods

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The moment I try:

```
java.util.Scanner.close();
```

or

`scanner.close()` or

`input.close()`

It sends all sorts of errors. But if I just don't use that, then it works fine.

What is it wrong???

```
import java.util.*;

public class Circles {

    static void circleMath() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter radius value: ");
        double radius = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The area is " + Math.PI * radius * radius);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         circleMath();

         scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of errors is it throwing?

Answer (score 0):

Close scanner for the method you define it, not from the main method. Close it in the circleMath() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close using the handle of the Scanner, which is input, not scanner, and as other answer notes, it needs to be closed in the function it was created in:

```
static void circleMath() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter radius value: ");
    double radius = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The area is " + Math.PI * radius * radius);
    input.close();

}
```

And eliminate the scanner.close() line in main. That should do it.